# Signature request message readable and not readable

Tags: metamask, signature, message

I noticed when metamask pops up with a  signature request, some dapp shows message in gibberish hex format which is unreadable to human and another dapp displays it in nicely formatted sentences which is readable. What's the difference?

Aren't they all using `personal.sign` where it takes string message?

I heard eip712 was introduced to improve showing as hex in message to be more human readable with json format, but kinda confused when I see readable sentences in signature request message section.